# Ember.js View without Wrapping Div?

Tags: ember.js, ember-1

I have a 3 column layout in my app. I'm using Semantic UI. So, the layout is:

```
<div class='ui celled grid'>
  <div class='left column'>...</div>
  <div class='middle column'>...</div>
  <div class='right column'>...</div>
</div>
```

So, straightforward.

In my `application.hbs` it is simply:

```
<div class='ui celled grid'>
  <div class='left column'><!-- menu --></div>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

And the other 2 columns are in my sub-controller/templates. And this works fine until I need a `View`. If I need a `View`, then Ember makes the HTML layout become:

```
<div class='ui celled grid'>
  <div class='left column'><!-- menu --></div>
  <div class='ember-view'>
    <div class='middle column'><!-- content --></div>
    <div class='right column'><!-- content --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the wrapping `<div class='ember-view'>` breaks my layout. Because I don't always need a `View` I need a way to make the HTML the same for with or without a `View`.

At this point, I see 2 solutions. I'll either have to rework my layout in some way (that I'm yet to work out). Or I can get rid of the wrapping div.

But is it possible to get rid of the wrapping div? I tried this:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: null
});
```

But that doesn't work. I also tried a `span`, but that still breaks my layout.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try using

```
tagName:''
```

The empty string as the tagName's value on your view.

Update:
When I brought this to the attention of ember.js contributors, they suggested inheriting the view from

```
Ember._MetamorphView
```

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4790

Comment: That worked. I'm embarrassed to say I didn't try that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, this caused side-effects, and broke my layout elsewhere. So, I guess, not supported after all.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for doing that. The _MetamorphView solved the issues I was seeing. I think I'm going to change my layout to make the way the layout work track more closely to my route pattern(s). In general, it works well, but I have some special cases (like this one) where it breaks.